# Using Google Chrome's console to perform searches

Tags: google-chrome

I work at a gym at the front desk. The website we use takes awhile to navigate using the GUI. This console in the Google Chrome browser seems pretty powerful. Can someone please direct me to some sort of tutorial or even answer this question yourself?

How would I use the Google Chrome console (inspect element > console) to perform searches using the website's search ability?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This would unfortunately be highly specific to how the website works. This is not to say it is necessarily impossible, but depending on how and with what technologies the website was built it could take a while to figure it all out (barring getting knowledge from who developed the site).

Comment: Basically you want to go to some website, open the console with F12 or inspection and with some javascript magic execute a search using the website search form? if that's so, provide an exemple with screenshot, search input and expected result you want to see in the console. Meanwhile you will need a lot of research on how to use jquery Ajax or any other JS library.

Comment: Welcome to programming. Prepare to have your mind blown.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need some basic understanding of javascript and DOM to do this.**

If your site has a simple form for searching, you could use something like this.

```
document.getElementById('IdOfSearchField').value = 'test';
document.getElementById('IdOfSearchForm').submit();
```

What is does is that it fiends the searchfield and sets its value to "test" and then it submits the search form.

On [this site](http://www.legimus.se/) (sorry for it being in Swedish, it was the one I was currently working on) you could use the following to search for 'test'.

```
document.getElementById('query').value = 'test'; document.getElementById('SpeedSearchForm').submit();
```

If your site has jQuery loaded you could simplify this a bit.

```
$('#query').val('test'); $('#SpeedSearchForm').submit();
```

Another way of doing it would be to navigate directly to the searchresult-page with the proper querystring (if that is supported by your website. In my sample case, it would look like this (because the search page is located at /search and just need the querystring `query` to work).

```
window.location = '/search?query=test';
```

But as ajp15243 noted in the comments on the question, it all depends on how your site is built. It's also a bit messy to type all that for every search.

Comment: Thanks Karl! Right, it would be tough to type all that code every time I searched. The goal here is to use the console to search the site without having to load the "Find User" or "Member Future Appointments" page. So I'm not sure this will work without having the Search field and Submit button on the actual page. I was hoping to call some sort of Javascript function? I think they include the same .JS files on every page.

Comment: I'll try to get more specific details on how this site's search works.